# Shortcut that set at "switching to another layout" blocks other shortcuts

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I use ALT+SHIFT as keyboard layout. This combination set at "switching to another layout" parameter of the Keyboard config. But if I want to use some combination that contains the 'switching layout' one, for example ALT+SHIFT+O, it will not work, and language will be changed.
How to fix this?

**Repository "ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys" wont work.**

Operating System: Linux Mint 21.2
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
Architecture: x86-64